# putting variable count into a list

Tags: python, list

I've got two lists:

```
    option_title = ['attack', 'defend', 'coattack', 'codefend']
    option_frequency = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I'm a newbie to python and I've had a few cracks at it, but how do I add the number of times a variable was used previously in my game to add to the option_frequency list - matching the titles of the first list???

Comment: zip(option_title, option_frequency)

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure what you're attempting to do, but are you only interested in recording the number of times the keywords/actions are used? If that's the case, a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) may be what you're looking for:

```
option_dict = {"attack": 0, "defend": 0, "coattack": 0, "codefend": 0}
option_dict["attack"] += 1
print "\n".join([key + " * " + str(option_dict[key]) for key in option_dict])
```

prints

```
codefend * 0
attack * 1
defend * 0
coattack * 0
```

If you should need to iterate over the codewords only, you can use `dict.keys()`:

```
print option_dict.keys()
```

which prints

```
['codefend', 'attack', 'defend', 'coattack']
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do is basically add the number of times the variable is used, and then use the list (with that recorded number for each variable) to display the frequency of each variable in a ' * ' in the output.

Comment: So...does my answer using `dict` solve your problem?

Comment: Changed my code slightly to print it with the "keyword * count" notation I think you were asking for...does my answer fit your needs? If not, please specify why not and what output you would expect seeing.

Comment: You don't need to call dict.keys, might also be easier just iterate over .items

Comment: @PadraicCunningham agreed, thanks for the input. Removed `.keys()` instead of printing with `.items()`, since OP wanted the output in that specific `*` format.

Comment: `print("\n".join(["{} * {}".format(attack,count) for attack,count in option_dict.items()]))`

Comment: I appreciate that this also prints it in that format, but is this really more readable or bear any other advantage in comparison with my solution?

Comment: not that it matters a great deal in this but using .items would generally be more efficient than doing lookups. I think it is definitely more readable .

Answer (score 0):

User [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) :

```
>>> zip(option_title, option_frequency)
>>> [('attack', 0), ('defend', 0), ('coattack', 0), ('codefend', 0)]
```